# On the definition of a local model in the linear case

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The local model of a totally ramified extension is defined in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205050) as follow:

[image: Definition]

1. What does the writer means by the fact that $\mathcal{F}_i$ are locally direct summand of $\mathcal{O}_S$ modules?
2. What does the writer means by $\mathrm{det}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(T-\Pi|\mathcal{F}_i)$? I know for sure that each $\mathcal{F}_i$ is stable under $\pi\otimes 1$ but i can't see how he defines the determinant over $\mathcal{O}_S$.

Comment: For $1.$ I think this means that $\mathcal{F}_i \subset \Lambda_{i,S}$ and if one sees the inclusions as one of $O_S$-modules, then locally on $S$, $\mathcal{F}_i \oplus \mathcal{G}_i=\Lambda_{i,S}$ for some $O_S$-module $\mathcal{G}_i$